# Java cache library without concurrency

Tags: java

Is there any Java cache library, similar to Guava's `LoadingCache`, but without support for concurrency?

I will be using the cache from a single thread, however I need features such as lazy loading and eviction

Comment: Why do you mind the concurrency support?

Comment: Which one did you tried or checked?

Comment: @shmosel I'm hoping it could achieve better performance without the complexity of multi-threading support

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out at local Cacheonix. Internally it uses key sharding so the impact of multi-threading support is close to non-existent.